# How did Talha bin Ubaidullah die?

Tags: history, sahaba, islamic-events, shia-sunni, battle-of-jamal

Talha bin Ubaidullah (may Allah be pleased with him) was one of the [Ashara al-Mubasharîn bi-l-Janna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_of_the_ten_promised_paradise).

How did he die? Was it natural death? or, he died in battle?

I would like to listen to both Sunni and Shi'a views, so please declare your view (to which sect it belongs) in the answer.

Also I hope to see only answers with proofs/citations/references, answers that doesn't provide any kind of source will be utterly rejected.

Comment: Good question, but why he? What is it that makes you interested in him spesifically?

Comment: @yasar11732: Because Talha is one figure of the battles that came after the death of Khalife Othman Ibn Affan (may Allah be pleased with both of them), and there are difference between Sunni and Shi'a views about his role and death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talha Bin Abeedullah was killed during the battle of Jamal by Marwaan bin Al Hakam.

> عَنْ قَيْسٍ، قَالَ:
>
> رَأَيْتُ مَرْوَانَ بنَ الحَكَمِ حِيْنَ رَمَى طَلْحَةَ يَوْمَئِذٍ
>   بِسَهْمٍ، فَوَقَعَ فِي رُكْبَتِهِ، فَمَا زَالَ يَنْسَحُّ حَتَّى مَاتَ.
>
> it is reported that Qais said that he saw Marwaan bin Al-Hakam who
>   threw an arrow at Talha bin Ubaydullah that day, he fell to his knees,and after a while he died.

Source (in Arabic): http://www.saaid.net/Doat/alarbi/24.htm